# Customised Emailable report is not generating in TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm running my automation test scripts which are created using TestNg Framework. Now I need to generate report and send mail management.. I'm using below code to generate report but it is not working.

Java code to generate report:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    import java.text.NumberFormat;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Comparator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.util.TreeSet;

    import org.testng.IReporter;
    import org.testng.IResultMap;
    import org.testng.ISuite;
    import org.testng.ISuiteResult;
    import org.testng.ITestContext;
    import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;
    import org.testng.ITestResult;
    import org.testng.Reporter;
    import org.testng.log4testng.Logger;
    import org.testng.reporters.util.StackTraceTools;
    import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;

    /**
     * Reported designed to render self-contained HTML top down view of a testing
     * suite.
     * 
     * @author Paul Mendelson
     * @since 5.2
     * @version $Revision$
     */
    public class EmailableReporter implements IReporter {
      private static final Logger L = Logger.getLogger(EmailableReporter.class);

      // ~ Instance fields ------------------------------------------------------

      private PrintWriter m_out;

      private int m_row;

      private int m_methodIndex;

      private int m_rowTotal;

      // ~ Methods --------------------------------------------------------------

      /** Creates summary of the run */
      public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xml, List<ISuite> suites, String outdir) {
        try {
          m_out = createWriter(outdir);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
          L.error("output file", e);
          return;
        }
        startHtml(m_out);
        generateSuiteSummaryReport(suites);
        generateMethodSummaryReport(suites);
        generateMethodDetailReport(suites);
        endHtml(m_out);
        m_out.flush();
        m_out.close();
      }

      protected PrintWriter createWriter(String outdir) throws IOException {
        return new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(outdir, "email-report.html"))));
      }

      /** Creates a table showing the highlights of each test method with links to the method details */
      protected void generateMethodSummaryReport(List<ISuite> suites) {
        m_methodIndex = 0;
        m_out.println("<a id=\"summary\"></a>");
        startResultSummaryTable("passed");
        for (ISuite suite : suites) {
          if(suites.size()>1) {
            titleRow(suite.getName(), 4);
          }
          Map<String, ISuiteResult> r = suite.getResults();
          for (ISuiteResult r2 : r.values()) {
            ITestContext test = r2.getTestContext();
            resultSummary(test.getFailedConfigurations(), test.getName(), "failed", " (configuration methods)");
            resultSummary(test.getFailedTests(), test.getName(), "failed", "");
            resultSummary(test.getSkippedConfigurations(), test.getName(), "skipped", " (configuration methods)");
            resultSummary(test.getSkippedTests(), test.getName(), "skipped", "");
            resultSummary(test.getPassedTests(), test.getName(), "passed", "");
          }
        }
        m_out.println("</table>");
      }

      /** Creates a section showing known results for each method */
      protected void generateMethodDetailReport(List<ISuite> suites) {
        m_methodIndex = 0;
        for (ISuite suite : suites) {
          Map<String, ISuiteResult> r = suite.getResults();
          for (ISuiteResult r2 : r.values()) {
            if (r.values().size() > 0) {
              m_out.println("<h1>" + r2.getTestContext().getName() + "</h1>");
            }
            resultDetail(r2.getTestContext().getFailedConfigurations(), "failed");
            resultDetail(r2.getTestContext().getFailedTests(), "failed");
            resultDetail(r2.getTestContext().getSkippedConfigurations(), "skipped");
            resultDetail(r2.getTestContext().getSkippedTests(), "skipped");
            resultDetail(r2.getTestContext().getPassedTests(), "passed");
          }
        }
      }

      /**
       * @param tests
       */
      private void resultSummary(IResultMap tests, String testname, String style, String details) {
        if (tests.getAllResults().size() > 0) {
          StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
          String lastc = "";
          int mq = 0;
          int cq = 0;
          for (ITestNGMethod method : getMethodSet(tests)) {
            m_row += 1;
            m_methodIndex += 1;
            String cname = method.getTestClass().getName();
            if (mq == 0) {
              titleRow(testname + " &#8212; " + style + details, 4);
            }
            if (!cname.equalsIgnoreCase(lastc)) {
              if (mq > 0) {
                cq += 1;
                m_out.println("<tr class=\"" + style
                    + (cq % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd") + "\">" + "<td rowspan=\""
                    + mq + "\">" + lastc + buff);
              }
              mq = 0;
              buff.setLength(0);
              lastc = cname;
            }
            Set<ITestResult> result_set = tests.getResults(method);
            long end = Long.MIN_VALUE;
            long start = Long.MAX_VALUE;
            for (ITestResult ans : tests.getResults(method)) {
              if (ans.getEndMillis() > end) {
                end = ans.getEndMillis();
              }
              if (ans.getStartMillis() < start) {
                start = ans.getStartMillis();
              }
            }
            mq += 1;
            if (mq > 1) {
              buff.append("<tr class=\"" + style + (cq % 2 == 0 ? "odd" : "even")
                  + "\">");
            }
            buff.append("<td><a href=\"#m" + m_methodIndex + "\">"
                + qualifiedName(method) + "</a></td>" + "<td class=\"numi\">"
                + result_set.size() + "</td><td class=\"numi\">" + (end - start)
                + "</td></tr>");
          }
          if (mq > 0) {
            cq += 1;
            m_out.println("<tr class=\"" + style + (cq % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd")
                + "\">" + "<td rowspan=\"" + mq + "\">" + lastc + buff);
          }
        }
      }

      /** Starts and defines columns result summary table */
      private void startResultSummaryTable(String style) {
        tableStart(style);
        m_out.println("<tr><th>Class</th>"
                + "<th>Method</th><th># of<br/>Scenarios</th><th>Time<br/>(Msecs)</th></tr>");
        m_row = 0;
      }

      private String qualifiedName(ITestNGMethod method) {
        String addon = "";
        if (method.getGroups().length > 0
            && !"basic".equalsIgnoreCase(method.getGroups()[0])) {
          addon = " (" + method.getGroups()[0] + ")";
        }
        return method.getMethodName() + addon;
      }

      private void resultDetail(IResultMap tests, final String style) {
        if (tests.getAllResults().size() > 0) {
          int row = 0;
          for (ITestNGMethod method : getMethodSet(tests)) {
            row += 1;
            m_methodIndex += 1;
            String cname = method.getTestClass().getName();
            m_out.println("<a id=\"m" + m_methodIndex + "\"></a><h2>" + cname + ":"
                + method.getMethodName() + "</h2>");
            int rq = 0;
            Set<ITestResult> resultSet = tests.getResults(method);
            for (ITestResult ans : resultSet) {
              rq += 1;
              Object[] parameters = ans.getParameters();
              boolean hasParameters = parameters != null && parameters.length > 0;
              if (hasParameters) {
                if (rq == 1) {
                  tableStart("param");
                  m_out.print("<tr>");
                  for (int x = 1; x <= parameters.length; x++) {
                    m_out
                        .print("<th style=\"padding-left:1em;padding-right:1em\">Parameter #"
                            + x + "</th>");
                  }
                  m_out.println("</tr>");
                }
                m_out.print("<tr" + (rq % 2 == 0 ? " class=\"stripe\"" : "") + ">");
                for (Object p : parameters) {
                  m_out
                      .println("<td style=\"padding-left:.5em;padding-right:2em\">"
                          + (p != null ? p.toString() : "null") + "</td>");
                }
                m_out.println("</tr>");
              }
              List<String> msgs = Reporter.getOutput(ans);
              boolean hasReporterOutput = msgs.size() > 0;
              Throwable exception=ans.getThrowable();
              boolean hasThrowable = exception!=null;
              if (hasReporterOutput||hasThrowable) {
                String indent = " style=\"padding-left:3em\"";
                if (hasParameters) {
                  m_out.println("<tr" + (rq % 2 == 0 ? " class=\"stripe\"" : "")
                      + "><td" + indent + " colspan=\"" + parameters.length + "\">");
                } 
                else {
                  m_out.println("<div" + indent + ">");
                }
                if (hasReporterOutput) {
                  if(hasThrowable)
                    m_out.println("<h3>Test Messages</h3>");
                  for (String line : msgs) {
                    m_out.println(line + "<br/>");
                  }
                }
                if(hasThrowable) {
                  boolean wantsMinimalOutput = ans.getStatus()==ITestResult.SUCCESS;
                  if(hasReporterOutput)
                    m_out.println("<h3>"
                        +(wantsMinimalOutput?"Expected Exception":"Failure")
                        +"</h3>");
                  generateExceptionReport(exception,method);
                }
                if (hasParameters) {
                  m_out.println("</td></tr>");
                } 
                else {
                  m_out.println("</div>");
                }
              }
              if (hasParameters) {
                if (rq == resultSet.size()) {
                  m_out.println("</table>");
                }
              }
            }
            m_out.println("<p class=\"totop\"><a href=\"#summary\">back to summary</a></p>");
          }
        }
      }

      protected void generateExceptionReport(Throwable exception,ITestNGMethod method) {
        generateExceptionReport(exception, method, exception.getLocalizedMessage());
      }

      private void generateExceptionReport(Throwable exception,ITestNGMethod method,String title) {
        m_out.println("<p>" + escape(title) + "</p>");
        StackTraceElement[] s1= exception.getStackTrace();
        Throwable t2= exception.getCause();
        if(t2 == exception) {
          t2= null;
        }
        int maxlines= Math.min(100,StackTraceTools.getTestRoot(s1, method));
        for(int x= 0; x <= maxlines; x++) {
          m_out.println((x>0 ? "<br/>at " : "") + escape(s1[x].toString()));
        }
        if(maxlines < s1.length) {
          m_out.println("<br/>" + (s1.length-maxlines) + " lines not shown");
        }
        if(t2 != null) {
          generateExceptionReport(t2, method, "Caused by " + t2.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
      }

      private static String escape(String string) {
        if(null == string) return string;
        return string.replaceAll("<", "&lt;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;");
      }

      /**
       * @param tests
       * @return
       */
      private Collection<ITestNGMethod> getMethodSet(IResultMap tests) {
        Set r = new TreeSet<ITestNGMethod>(new TestSorter<ITestNGMethod>());
        r.addAll(tests.getAllMethods());
        return r;
      }

      public void generateSuiteSummaryReport(List<ISuite> suites) {
        tableStart("param");
        m_out.print("<tr><th>Test</th>");
        tableColumnStart("Methods<br/>Passed");
        tableColumnStart("Scenarios<br/>Passed");
        tableColumnStart("# skipped");
        tableColumnStart("# failed");
        tableColumnStart("Total<br/>Time");
        tableColumnStart("Included<br/>Groups");
        tableColumnStart("Excluded<br/>Groups");
        m_out.println("</tr>");
        NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");
        int qty_tests = 0;
        int qty_pass_m = 0;
        int qty_pass_s = 0;
        int qty_skip = 0;
        int qty_fail = 0;
        long time_start = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        long time_end = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        for (ISuite suite : suites) {
          if (suites.size() > 1) {
            titleRow(suite.getName(), 7);
          }
          Map<String, ISuiteResult> tests = suite.getResults();
          for (ISuiteResult r : tests.values()) {
            qty_tests += 1;
            ITestContext overview = r.getTestContext();
            startSummaryRow(overview.getName());
            int q = getMethodSet(overview.getPassedTests()).size();
            qty_pass_m += q;
            summaryCell(q,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            q = overview.getPassedTests().size();
            qty_pass_s += q;
            summaryCell(q,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            q = getMethodSet(overview.getSkippedTests()).size();
            qty_skip += q;
            summaryCell(q,0);
            q = getMethodSet(overview.getFailedTests()).size();
            qty_fail += q;
            summaryCell(q,0);
            time_start = Math.min(overview.getStartDate().getTime(), time_start);
            time_end = Math.max(overview.getEndDate().getTime(), time_end);
            summaryCell(formatter.format(
                (overview.getEndDate().getTime() - overview.getStartDate().getTime()) / 1000.)
                + " seconds", true);
            summaryCell(overview.getIncludedGroups());
            summaryCell(overview.getExcludedGroups());
            m_out.println("</tr>");
          }
        }
        if (qty_tests > 1) {
          m_out.println("<tr class=\"total\"><td>Total</td>");
          summaryCell(qty_pass_m,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
          summaryCell(qty_pass_s,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
          summaryCell(qty_skip,0);
          summaryCell(qty_fail,0);
          summaryCell(formatter.format((time_end - time_start) / 1000.) + " seconds", true);
          m_out.println("<td colspan=\"2\">&nbsp;</td></tr>");
        }
        m_out.println("</table>");
      }

      private void summaryCell(String[] val) {
        StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
        for (String v : val) {
          b.append(v + " ");
        }
        summaryCell(b.toString(),true);
      }

      private void summaryCell(String v,boolean isgood) {
        m_out.print("<td class=\"numi"+(isgood?"":"_attn")+"\">" + v + "</td>");
      }

      private void startSummaryRow(String label) {
        m_row += 1;
        m_out.print("<tr" + (m_row % 2 == 0 ? " class=\"stripe\"" : "")
                + "><td style=\"text-align:left;padding-right:2em\">" + label
                + "</td>");
      }

      private void summaryCell(int v,int maxexpected) {
        summaryCell(String.valueOf(v),v<=maxexpected);
        m_rowTotal += v;
      }

      /**
       * 
       */
      private void tableStart(String cssclass) {
        m_out.println("<table cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0"
            + (cssclass != null ? " class=\"" + cssclass + "\""
                : " style=\"padding-bottom:2em\"") + ">");
        m_row = 0;
      }

      private void tableColumnStart(String label) {
        m_out.print("<th class=\"numi\">" + label + "</th>");
      }

      private void titleRow(String label, int cq) {
        m_out.println("<tr><th colspan=\"" + cq + "\">" + label + "</th></tr>");
        m_row = 0;
      }

      protected void writeStyle(String[] formats,String[] targets) {

      }

      /** Starts HTML stream */
      protected void startHtml(PrintWriter out) {
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd\">");
        out.println("<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>TestNG:  Unit Test</title>");
        out.println("<style type=\"text/css\">");
        out.println("table caption,table.info_table,table.param,table.passed,table.failed {margin-bottom:10px;border:1px solid #000099;border-collapse:collapse;empty-cells:show;}");
        out.println("table.info_table td,table.info_table th,table.param td,table.param th,table.passed td,table.passed th,table.failed td,table.failed th {");
        out.println("border:1px solid #000099;padding:.25em .5em .25em .5em");
        out.println("}");
        out.println("table.param th {vertical-align:bottom}");
        out.println("td.numi,th.numi,td.numi_attn {");
        out.println("text-align:right");
        out.println("}");
        out.println("tr.total td {font-weight:bold}");
        out.println("table caption {");
        out.println("text-align:center;font-weight:bold;");
        out.println("}");
        out.println("table.passed tr.stripe td,table tr.passedodd td {background-color: #00AA00;}");
        out.println("table.passed td,table tr.passedeven td {background-color: #33FF33;}");
        out.println("table.passed tr.stripe td,table tr.skippedodd td {background-color: #cccccc;}");
        out.println("table.passed td,table tr.skippedodd td {background-color: #dddddd;}");
        out.println("table.failed tr.stripe td,table tr.failedodd td,table.param td.numi_attn {background-color: #FF3333;}");
        out.println("table.failed td,table tr.failedeven td,table.param tr.stripe td.numi_attn {background-color: #DD0000;}");
        out.println("tr.stripe td,tr.stripe th {background-color: #E6EBF9;}");
        out.println("p.totop {font-size:85%;text-align:center;border-bottom:2px black solid}");
        out.println("div.shootout {padding:2em;border:3px #4854A8 solid}");
        out.println("</style>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
      }

      /** Finishes HTML stream */
      protected void endHtml(PrintWriter out) {
        out.println("</body></html>");
      }

      // ~ Inner Classes --------------------------------------------------------
      /** Arranges methods by classname and method name */
      private class TestSorter<T extends ITestNGMethod> implements Comparator {
        // ~ Methods -------------------------------------------------------------

        /** Arranges methods by classname and method name */
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
          int r = ((T) o1).getTestClass().getName().compareTo(((T) o2).getTestClass().getName());
          if (r == 0) {
            r = ((T) o1).getMethodName().compareTo(((T) o2).getMethodName());
          }
          return r;
        }
      }
    }
```

My testng.xml is:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="com.company.common.EmailableReporter" />
    </listeners>

    <test name="SanityTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.company.tests.PresenceTest" />


        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Can somebody help me to make it work.

Comment: Hi @lingaraj please check by putting `@Override` above `generateReport` method.

Comment: hi @lingaraj... I tried out your code...its working for me...its generating email-report.html with your desired contents.